# How to call method from different Module

Tags: java, spring, maven, methods, module

Is there a way to call a method from a different Module in Java?
For example i want to call method from B in A, but
B pom file already has A dependency and if i put in A pom file B dependency then it's a loop and still doesn't work, automatically compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible as long as the module is added as a dependency in your POM and the method is public